# Purpose of TransferHttpCacheModule when using BrowserTransferStateModule

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am working on an Angular Universal application and trying to prevent duplicate HTTP calls on server/client in the most efficient way possible. I have been able to accomplish the task by utilizing `ServerTransferStateModule` on `app.server.module` and `BrowserTransferStateModule` on `app.module`. When making my HTTP call, I either get or set a state variable using `TransferState`.

This works. My question is, what is the purpose of `TransferHttpCacheModule` because for me it works without using it, but other examples say it's necessary. It does not appear necessary for me so I would like to know how it's supposed to fit in. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I did some more testing and it seems like `TransferHttpCacheModule` does the job automatically when you're utilizing HttpClient. In my case, I was using `Restangular` so this didn't work out the box. Thanks. Hope this helps someone in the future.